# I am using content editable html loaded in uiwebview. I need the code to set the cursor position when the keyboard is hidden/shown

Tags: ios, uiwebview, contenteditable, evernote, rich-text-editor

I am using content editable html loaded in uiwebview. I need the code to set the cursor position when the keyboard is hidden/shown.

Currently when i click on webview keyboard comes up but the content gets hidden behind the keyboard. Same happens when i keeps pressing on return key the cursor/text goes behind the webview or is not visible.

For head start, i need the functionality like used in iPad Evernote application. In that you can see cursor never goes behind the keyboard, it always starts above the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using javascript for this. I'm using a class to keep the code little more organized (so you'll see some `this` in the code), but that's not necessary.

```
// this is used to get the current coordinates of the selection - not very efficient, so it shouldn't be called too often
this.updateOffset = function() {
  try{
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    if(this.tmpSpan==null){
      this.tmpSpan = document.createElement('span');
    }
    range.insertNode(this.tmpSpan);
    this.yOffset = this.tmpSpan.offsetTop;
    this.xOffset = this.tmpSpan.offsetLeft;
    this.tmpSpan.parentNode.removeChild(this.tmpSpan);
  }
  catch(exc){
    log('updateOffset:' + exc.toString());
  }
}

// eContent is the div with 'contenteditable', while visibleHeight is an int, set from objective-c (depending on where the webview is positioned, keyboard height and screen height)
this.scrollToVisible = function(){
  try {
    if(this.eContent.clientHeight>this.visibleHeight){
      this.updateOffset();
      if(this.yOffset<window.pageYOffset){
        window.scrollTo(0, this.yOffset);
      }
      else if(this.yOffset-window.pageYOffset>this.visibleHeight){
        window.scrollTo(0, this.yOffset-this.visibleHeight);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (exc){
    log('scrollToVisible: ', exc.toString());
  }
}
```

In objective-c I'm setting the visibleHeight during keyboard showing up, and afterwards call `scrollToVisible` when keyboard has finished showing.

```
-(void)setVisibleHeight:(int)height{
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"docState.visibleHeight=%d", height]];
}
-(void)scrollToVisible{
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"docState.scrollToVisible()"];
}
```

`scrollToVisible` is also called on the javascript events: onkeyup, onpaset, oncut, which fixes the issue when pressing 'return' or wrapping on multiple lines.

In case you decide to go this way, you'll need to be very careful when you scroll through javascript, otherwise it may cause some issues with UIWebview control (e.g: placing the cursor at the wrong positions, moving cursor automatically on the top of the document etc.)

**Edit**
Some clarification regarding the `visibleHeight`. From what I can remember, I used this because I wasn't able to get the actual visible height from javascript (`document.body.clientHeight` would also include the area behind the keyboard).

Since I'm presenting the `UIWebView` in full screen, I'm setting the visible height as follows:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    ...
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* aValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardRect = [aValue CGRectValue];
    CGRect kbRect = [self.window convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];
    _kbRect = kbRect;

    CGPoint sorigin = [self.superview convertPoint:self.frame.origin toView:nil];
    int visibleHeight = _kbRect.origin.y-sorigin.y-_tlbInputAccessory.frame.size.height-lkPadBottom; // _tlbInputAccessory is a custom accessory view
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"docState.setVisibleHeight(%d)", height]];
    ...
}
```

Note that I'm calling this from a subclass of `UIWebView`, so `self` will represent the `UIWebView` control.

Comment: how to call -(void)setVisibleHeight:(int)height i mean what is the height ?

Comment: @MoorthyTheBoss please see the edit for more info on `visibleHeight`.

Comment: thank you can you please tell me what is object called  lkPadBottom?

Comment: actually i want to move the curser when return button pressed like Evernote app i hope this question also same like what my need.. I think your code make the curser above the keyboard when its pop up..

Comment: @MoorthyTheBoss `lkPadBottom` is a constant, it's set to 20 in my case. I don't know how it works in Evernote, but this code is for keeping the cursor above the keyboard (by default, it gets hidden behind it in some situations). For scrolling when selection or text changes, I'm using javascript and handling scrolling manually on `onKeyUp`, `onPaste` and `onCut` events.

Comment: thank you your right.. can you have any example for onKeyUp, onPaste and onCut events. i'm very new to javascript..

Comment: something like `this.eContent.onkeyup = this.scrollToVisible;` should work (`this` may not be necessary in your case, depending on where you've defined `scrollToVisible`). Same for the other events.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42638/discussion-between-moorthy-the-boss-and-alex-i)